# Is it possible to replace the optical drive in your Macbook with an SSD, and designate that drive as a Windows 10 disk?

Tags: windows-10, mac, ssd, boot-camp

I have been trying to do this, and it has been a headache and a half.  I replaced my optical drive in my MB pro (mid-2012, running 10.11.6) with an Evo 860 SSD.  My idea was to keep my standard internal HD as my OS X drive, and dedicate this newly installed drive for Windows 10.

I will save the long winded explanation of everything I have tried to do to get this to work, I've been trying to figure this out for ~14 hours, it would take all day.  Upon Googling this issue I found some people saying it is impossible to get Windows 10 to install and boot from a HD that is not in the main bay of a Macbook.

Is this true?  Can anyone point me to a guide or something that shows otherwise?  The only thing I can find when trying to look into this is booting from Windows on an external/USB drive, which is obviously not what I am intending to do.

Worse comes to worst, I'll have to swap my new SSD with the older HD so it sits in the "first" drive bay.  But I'm more curious about whether anyone has accomplished what I am trying to do without the need to swap bays.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Windows 10 via bootcamp on an SSD in the optical drive slot](https://superuser.com/questions/1512561/installing-windows-10-via-bootcamp-on-an-ssd-in-the-optical-drive-slot)

Answer (score 0):

I did this years ago & don't remember the exact method - but it is possible.
The Mac doesn't care which disk is which or in what bay.

Basically, you set up Boot Camp Windows on the Mac drive, as normal… then you clone it to the other drive & delete [not 'uninstall'] the original.

Apps such as [WinClone](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone/), [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) & [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) can all do at least parts of this task.
Have a solid backup of your Mac drive before you start.

Note that if your Mac drive is APFS, then if you boot to Windows as default from the Startup Disk control panel, the only way to switch back is by holding alt at boot & selecting the Mac drive manually. [This is standard for all Boot Camp structures since APFS]
Alternatively, have a look at [Boot Runner](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/boot-runner/)

Late note: I just realised you said OS X 10.11.6 - in which case you will have no worries about APFS - it's all a lot easier with HFS. You might even want to have a look at [iPartition](https://coriolis-systems.com) which is now abandonware/freeware/donationware but still works perfectly well on HFS disks, so long as you're not using core storage.